# Export only .mp4 file extensions using PowerShell

Tags: shell, powershell, sharepoint, powershell-2.0

How would I be able to export only files that have a .mp4 file extension? I'm currently exporting all the files in a document library.

Example:
[image]

Code: I'm currently pulling in all the items from the Video library.

```html
# Add SharePoint Snapin to PowerShell                                         # $_.extension -eq $FileExtension
if((Get-PSSnapin | Where {$_.Name -eq "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"}) -eq $null) {
  Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
}
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://sourcevideo.f.com/"
$Data = foreach ($list in $web.Lists["Video"]) {
        if ($list.BaseType -eq “DocumentLibrary”){
            #if ($item -Like "*.mp4"){
                foreach ($item in $list.Items) {
                    $data = @{
                        "List Name" = $list.Title
                        "Created By" = $item["Author"]
                        "Created Date" = $item["Created"]
                        "Modified By" = $item["Editor"]
                        "Modified Date" = $item["Modified"]
                        "Item Name" = $item.File.Name
                        "URL"=$web.Site.MakeFullUrl("$($web.ServerRelativeUrl.TrimEnd('/'))/$($item.Url)");
                        }
                    New-Object PSObject -Property $data | Select "List Name", "Item Name", "Created By", "Created Date", "Modified By", "Modified Date", "URL"
                #}
            }
        
        }
        $web.Dispose()
    }
$Data  |  Export-Csv C:\Users\ptadmin\Desktop\process9.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this.

```
# Add SharePoint Snapin to PowerShell                                         # $_.extension -eq $FileExtension
if((Get-PSSnapin | Where {$_.Name -eq "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"}) -eq $null) {
  Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
}
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://sp:12001/"
$Data = foreach ($list in $web.Lists["MyDoc"]) {
        if ($list.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary"){
            #if ($item -Like "*.mp4"){
                foreach ($item in $list.Items) {
                $fileExtension= $item.File.Name.Split('.')[1]
                if($fileExtension -eq 'mp4'){
                    $data = @{
                        "List Name" = $list.Title
                        "Created By" = $item["Author"]
                        "Created Date" = $item["Created"]
                        "Modified By" = $item["Editor"]
                        "Modified Date" = $item["Modified"]
                        "Item Name" = $item.File.Name                       
                        "URL"=$web.Site.MakeFullUrl("$($web.ServerRelativeUrl.TrimEnd('/'))/$($item.Url)");
                        }
                    New-Object PSObject -Property $data | Select "List Name", "Item Name", "Created By", "Created Date", "Modified By", "Modified Date", "URL"
                #}
                }
            }

        }
        $web.Dispose()
    }
$Data  |  Export-Csv C:\Lee\Script\process9.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I would change the `$fileExtension= $item.File.Name.Split('.')[1]` into `$fileExtension= $item.File.Name.Split('.')[-1]` to make sure you get the last element. Otherwise, if a file is called `abc.def.mp4`, doing `$fileExtension= $item.File.Name.Split('.')[1]` would return `def`

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to export `*.mp4` files from a directory, simply do this:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Filter *.mp4
```

If you want to do this recursively over a directory,

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.mp4
```